# Expect new line

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I am trying to make a bash/expect script to ssh into an APC PDU (a powerstrip) and remotely restart an outlet based on a command line argument. So far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#usage: pdu.sh user pass ipaddr outletNum

set user [lrange $argv 0 0]
set pass [lrange $argv 1 1]
set ipaddr [lrange $argv 2 2]
set outlet [lrange $argv 3 3]

spawn ssh $user@$ipaddr

sleep 60

expect "*?assword*"
send "$pass\n"
expect ">"

sleep 5

send "1\n"
expect ">"
send "2\n"
expect ">"
send "1\n"
expect ">"

send "$outlet\n"
expect ">"
send "1\n"
expect ">"
send "2\n"
send "yes\n"
expect ">"
send "1\n"
send "yes\n"

send "exit\n"
```

So the spawning of the SSH works, and it enters the password correctly, but then after I'm connected to the PDU, and it shows the options interface, my script sends a 12 instead of 1 (enter) 2. Sorry if that's confusing. Here is what it does:

[image]

It shows a 12 instead of a 1 and then a newline and then a 2. I specifically have it send a newline after the 1 in this line `send "1\n"`

Why is the \n not working in this example? Thank you!

Comment: Usually `\r` represents "hitting enter", not `\n`

Comment: Thanks man. Also, do you guys know why it could be crashing after sending the outlet number? This is what it looks like after sending the argument "outlet" http://i.imgur.com/SlIOZdu.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expect use \r (carriage return) instead of \n (UNIX new line). 
Also you can simplify your expect  script a bit by:

```
expect {
 ">" {send "1\r"; exp_continue}
 # Next expect token and response and so on 
}
```